# Create a new object by merging two objects in a set having same Id and add the resulting object into a different set

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8, set, java-stream

I have a set of objects, ProductDetails with following fields,

```
public class ProductDetails {

    String productId;

    Set<CityQty> qtyByCities;

}

@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"name"})
public class CityQty {
    String name;
    int qty;
}
```

I want to convert this into a set of CityQty, where each city has the total qty of all the products.

Example Input:

```
[{"productId":"Item01","qtyByCities":[{"name":"New York", "qty":24},{"name":"Washington", "qty":68}]},
{"productId":"Item02","qtyByCities":[{"name":"New York", "qty":20}]}]
```

Example Output:

```
[{"name":"New York", "qty":44},{"name":"Washington", "qty":68}]
```

I've written the following code to achieve this:

```
Set<CityQty> cities = new HashSet<>();
setOfItems.stream().flatMap(product -> product.getQtyByCities().stream())
    .forEach(cityQty -> {
        String cityName = cityQty.getName();
        CityQty city = cities.stream()
                             .filter(cityQty -> cityQty.getName().equals(cityName))
                             .findFirst()
                             .orElse(new CityQty(cityName, 0));
        city.setQty(city.getQty() + cityQty.getQty());
        cities.add(city);
});
```

The above solution is working fine, but I'm looking for a more elegant solution, maybe using any Java 8 functionality that I'm missing here, that doesn't require me to iterate through the `cities` set for every iteration inside the `forEach` lambda.

Can this problem be solved more efficiently and concisely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leverage `Collectors` class. See [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) for more details. Here is an example using `groupingBy`:

```
Map<String, Integer> m = setOfItems.stream()
    .flatMap(product -> product.getQtyByCities().stream())
    .collect(groupingBy(CityQty::getName, summingInt(CityQty::getQty)));
```

You'll end up with a map: name - sum. If you want to get a set, you can use `map`:

```
m.entrySet().stream().map(e -> new CityQty(e.getKey(), e.getValue())).collect(toSet());
```